# PHP - Por quê devo colocar um IF no mysqli_prepare()

Tags: php, mysqli, if

No exemplo abordado no [Manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php) foi feito o uso do **if** antes da execução das instruções. Sei que o **if** é usado para comparações, qual comparação está sendo feita aqui? Segue o exemplo do website abaixo:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: O primeiro `if`, se a função `mysqli_connect_errno` retornar `1` (equivale a `true`), significa que houve um erro e o código irá parar por ali mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas me refiro ao if da pergunta, mysqli_prepare

Comment: O segundo é praticamente o mesmo. Se deu certo, executa os comandos. Senão, só fecha a conexão. Tutorialzinho porco. Se é pra não fazer nada com o erro, nem use o if. numa aplicação de verdade você vai parar e logar o erro pra poder consertar.

Comment: `$stmt` é uma variável que está sendo criada na hora da comparação, o _prepare_ irá trazer um resultado _boleano_, o que a mesma condição do primeiro `if`.

Comment: Como assim "deu certo", verificar se a query é válida?

Comment: Se o "prepare" foi bem sucedido, o "interior" do if é executado. Se a query contiver algum erro, ou qualquer outro problema ocorrer, a expressão do $stmt será false, portanto só vai ser executado o close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
```

Esse if verifica se a consulta não possui nenhum erro de sintaxe ou de 'execução' como violação de constraints, caso tenho sucesso faz a atribuição em `$stmt`. A ausência dele pode acarretar erro em `bind_param()` por `prepare()` ter retornado `false` no lugar de um objeto `mysqli_stmt` então o erro `Call to a member function`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, agora entendi.